# Add Thumbnail/Featured Image and excerpt to loop (multisite)

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I've tried some different things but I'm stuck.
I want to add a thumbnail/featured image to the loop. And if possible the websites excerpt also.

Here's what i have: [image]

```
function subsites_list_sites() {
    $subsites = get_sites();
    $returnHtml = '';    
    if ( ! empty ( $subsites ) ) {  
        $returnHtml .= '<div class="subsites-container">';
        foreach( $subsites as $subsite ) {

            $subsite_id = get_object_vars( $subsite )["blog_id"];
            $subsite_name = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->blogname;
            $subsite_link = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->siteurl;

            $returnHtml .= '
            <div class="subsite-item site-' . $subsite_id . '">
                <div class="thumb"><a href="' . $subsite_link . '">Here i want the featured image/thumbnail to display</a></div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="title">
                        <a href="' . $subsite_link . '"><h3 class="title">' . $subsite_name . '</h3></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <a class="excerpt" href="' . $subsite_link . '"><p>Here i want excerpt<p></a>
                        <a class="btn-link" href="' . $subsite_link . '">GO TO WEBSITE</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }
        $returnHtml .= '</div>';
    }
    return $returnHtml;
}
add_shortcode( 'subsites_list_sites_sc', 'subsites_list_sites' );
```

Comment: what image are you trying to get? Sites don't really have a featured image, posts do. Are you trying to get the theme screenshot? Or are you trying to get a snippet like something that would appear on a tweet or FB post?

Comment: Arh.. So there's no way to get an image to show? What i want is a featured image or something.... I create my own layouts, so each subsite is a layout and i want to show an overview with an image.

Comment: If the sites have different themes you could grab the screenshot of the theme for each site. https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Screenshot

Comment: you could also you the meta description of each blog as the excerpt for each tile.

Comment: It's the same theme on all sites... I'll insert it using pseudo in the beginning.. thank you so far :)